# Docusign 400 BadRequest for AddUser to account REST API

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I managed to get access token with my code,

```
  private async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        string refreshToken = string.Empty;
        string accessToken = string.Empty;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/oauth2/token");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        string body =
            "username=user%40company.net&password=mypassword&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc&grant_type=password&scope=api";               

        HttpContent content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        HttpResponseMessage messge = await client.PostAsync("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/oauth2/token", content);
        //string description = string.Empty;
        if (messge.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            dynamic returnObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

            var scope = returnObj.scope.Value;
            accessToken = returnObj.access_token.Value;

        }

        return accessToken;
    }
```

This gives me the access token,
Now I am trying to use that token and add a user to the account,

```
    private async Task<string> AddUser(string accessToken, string usersBaseUri)
    {
        usersBaseUri = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<myaccountId>/users";
        string resultStr = string.Empty;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(usersBaseUri);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);           


        DocuSignUser user = new DocuSignUser();
        user.Email = "user2@company.net";
        user.UserName = "user2@company.net";
        user.FirstName = "user2";
        user.LastName = "dev";

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        HttpContent content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage messge = await client.PostAsync(usersBaseUri, content);
        //string description = string.Empty;
        if (messge.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            dynamic returnObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

            var scope = returnObj.scope.Value;
            accessToken = returnObj.access_token.Value;
        }

        return resultStr;
    }
```

Here is the Docusign User class I use to serialize,

```
public class DocuSignUser
{
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

User api is not supported in the [.Net SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client). Therefor I had to write this code by referring to [Docusign Api test playground](http://iodocs.docusign.com/?utm_campaign=NC_DevCenter%20-%20Email%201%20-%20Key%20Information%20Jan%202015%20Update&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua) and checking the Request/Response with Fiddler.

Appreciate any help on this.

**EDIT**

Here is the POST request

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/156xxxx/users HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer *******<AccessToken>
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: demo.docusign.net
Content-Length: 100
Expect: 100-continue
    {"email":"user1@company.net","userName":"user1@company.net","firstName":"Sam1","lastName":"Cooper1"}
```

Comment: Please post the raw JSON your code produces (you can redact any confidential info if needed), otherwise it's very tough to debug.  With the raw JSON we're more likely to spot what the issue is.  You can enable Request Logging through your account preferences then post that log here.  As a side note, you can also try using the DocuSign API Explorer to see what the request SHOULD look like and compare to yours.

Comment: Updated the question with the POST request (Raw format).

Comment: @Ergin: I tried to refer to DocuSign API Explorer, but it does not have OAuth flow based api calls (It passes the Integrator Key, username and password in the request params). Also it does not have api calls for User management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer,

Issue was with the Json message.
Required Json format is in the following format as per [Api Guide](https://08d1d92f490618f41c65-8fb00e97ac499a7066a18ce9c66b019b.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf)

```
{
  "newUsers":[
     {         
        "email":"user@company.net",         
        "firstName":"name1",         
        "lastName":"lastname1",
        "password":"Password01",         
        "userName":"user1@bcompany.net"         
     }
   ]
}
```